# How can I copy all files with a certain extension into a single directory (without the directory structure)?

Tags: windows, command-line, file-transfer

I have been trying to copy all files in the various sub-directories that have a `JPG` extension located on `C:` into a single directory on `D:`. I don't want to preserve the directory structure.

This is as far as I have gotten:

```
for /r C:\ %f in (*.jpg) do @copy "%f" D:\pictures
```

After this point, I'm asked if I want to overwrite `D:\pictures`. If I answer `yes`, I wind up with a single file, and if I answer no, no files get copied.

I also tried adding `/y` at the end of the command, but it just overwrites the preceding files leaving only the last one.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
for /r C:\ %f in (*.jpg) do @copy "%f" D:\pictures\
```

Explanation:

The command `copy "%f" D:\pictures` copies the file `%f` to the location `D:\pictures`, which is the file `pictures` in the directory `D:\`.

Adding a trailing `\` to make sure `copy` treats `pictures` as a directory.

If you copy multiple files to a single location (e. g., `copy *.* D:\backup`), `copy` automatically treats `backup` as a directory. But this is not the case when you copy a single file.

Comment: What to do if there is more than 1 file with the same name at different directories? Would the above command overwrite the fist copied file with the last one? How can we prevent this? Thanks.

Comment: @EmmadKareem: None of the standard copy utilities (copy, xcopy, robocopy) have a built-in function to prevent clobbering. You should ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

for /R c:\ %%1 in ("*.txt") do @xcopy "%%1" d:\txttemp%%~p1  /e/i/s/q/h

this code will copy without over write and will create folders and sub folders